# Python 3.2 input date function

Tags: python, datetime, input, python-3.x

I would like to write a function that takes a date entered by the user, stores it with the shelve function and prints the date thirty days later when called.

I'm trying to start with something simple like:

```
import datetime

def getdate():
    date1 = input(datetime.date)
    return date1

getdate()

print(date1)
```

This obviously doesn't work.

I've used the answers to the above question and now have that section of my program working! Thanks!
Now for the next part:

I'm trying to write a simple program that takes the date the way you instructed me to get it and adds 30 days.

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

d = datetime.date(2013, 1, 1)
print(d)
year, month, day = map(int, d.split('-'))
d = datetime.date(year, month, day)
d = dplanted.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
d = datetime.date(d)+timedelta(days=30)
print(d)
```

This gives me an error:
        year, month, day = map(int, d.split('-'))
    AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'split'

Ultimately what I want is have 01/01/2013 + 30 days and print 01/30/2013.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `input()` method can *only* take text from the terminal. You'll thus have to figure out a way to parse that text and turn it into a date.

You could go about that in two different ways:

- Ask the user to enter the 3 parts of a date separately, so call `input()` three times, turn the results into integers, and build a date:

  ```
  year = int(input('Enter a year'))
  month = int(input('Enter a month'))
  day = int(input('Enter a day'))
  date1 = datetime.date(year, month, day)
  ```
- Ask the user to enter the date in a *specific format*, then turn that format into the three numbers for year, month and day:

  ```
  date_entry = input('Enter a date in YYYY-MM-DD format')
  year, month, day = map(int, date_entry.split('-'))
  date1 = datetime.date(year, month, day)
  ```

Both these approaches are examples; no error handling has been included for example, you'll need to read up on Python exception handling to figure that out for yourself. :-)

Comment: `dateutil` can parse dates in various string formats automatically.

Comment: @wRAR: Sure, but that's the next level; the important part is understanding how `input()` works.

Comment: thank you for the guidance, and I do appreciate: "you'll need to read up on Python exception handling to figure that out for yourself. :-)" You're forcing me to learn ;)

Comment: On this line, "map(int, date_entry.split('-'))" what does the "map" do? And also, because I have found the split method, (is it a method?), when it says date_entry.split('-'), are you telling it to split the value at each dash? or does it recognize the seperation of year, month, day and create a dash between each value?

Comment: @user2136162: see http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split and http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map :-) `str.split()` returns a tuple with the elements between the split string (so `'abc-def'.split('-')` gives you `('abc', 'def')`. `map(callable, sequence)` calls the callable for each element in the sequence, so the strings are mapped to integers.

Comment: Ok, back to the books! Thanks again for the help.

Comment: This is not pythonic, consider using strptime to parse datetime.

Comment: @ArthurKhazbs: that depends entirely on your use-cases. There is nothing pythonic or unpythonic about UI design. `datetime.strptime()` is just one of the options in the arsenal, but not that it is *not available on `date`*. So you'd have to use `datetime.strptime(date_entry, "%Y-%m-%d").date()`, and has different error output for wrong dates. Try to enter `2019-2-29`, `strptime` gives you a very cryptic error message: *ValueError: unconverted data remains: 9*, whereas the method in my answer gives you *ValueError: day is out of range for month*.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks. I have been trying to figure out how to add info to datetime.datetime(xxx) and  this explains it nicely.  It's as follows

`datetime.datetime(year,month, day, hour, minute, second)`  with parameters all integer.  It works!

Answer (score 2):

Use the dateutils module

```
    from dateutil import parser

    date = parser.parse(input("Enter date: "))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use

```py
import datetime
time_str = input("enter time in this format yyyy-mm-dd")
time=datetime.datetime.strptime(time_str, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

datetime.datetime.strptime() strips the given string in the format you give it.

Answer (score -1):

Check the library as

import datetime

and follow syntax

date = datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1)