# Number of days between two user input dates

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm trying to get the number of days between two user input days.

This is what I have:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

print( now.day )

print( now.year )

print( now.month )

salario = float(input("¿Cuál es su salario mensual en colones? "))

print ("Fecha inicial de la incapacidad")
dia1 = int(input("Día: "))
mes1 = int(input("Mes: "))
ano1 = int(input("Año: "))
fecha1 = datetime.date(dia1, mes1, ano1)
print ("Fecha final de la incapacidad")
dia2 = int(input("Día: "))
mes2 = int(input("Mes: "))
ano2 = int(input("Año: "))
fecha2 = datetime.date(dia2, mes2, ano2)

diasinc = fecha2 - fecha2
print (diasinc.day)
```

(Based on the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226898/python-3-2-input-date-function)) entry)

I enter dia1 = 20, mes1 = 5, ano1 = 2017, for the date May 20th, 2017.

But I keep getting "ValueError: day is out of range for month".

Can anyone explain this error to me? Do you know how I can change this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`date` get the arguments in the order `year, month, day`. You feed them in the opposite order - and that makes an invalid date (you cant have the May 2017th, 5).

Try instead

```
fecha1 = datetime.date(ano1, mes1, dia1)
```

<sub>(same goes for `fecha2`)</sub>

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe it was that simple hehe. Do you know how I can subtract the two dates to get the number of days in between them?

Comment: @IreneCastañeda with `diasinc.days`. you forgot the `s`

Comment: yes sorry, when I tried to do that the website said to wait for half an hour to end.

Answer (score 2):

The arguments for `date` are `year`, `month`, `days` in order. According to your input the day is set to `2017` which is out of permissible range for days in a month. That is why the error.

Try -

`fecha1 = datetime.date(ano1, mes1, dia1)`

same goes for the next one