# How to compare dates (in string)?

Tags: python, date

I want to determine the cost by specific rules between two dates. The problem is that the input is in not in a date format but as:

6 6 2020 
9 9 2020

The conditions are as follows:

1. If same day, there is a fixed cost of 20.
2. If after a day but still within a month cost = 30 * (the number of days).
3. If after a month but still within a year, the cost = 1000 * (the number of months).
4. If after a year in which it was created,then there is a fixed cost of 20000.

How do I compare them by changing only the cost( ) ?

what I have tried is far from perfect and already uses too many branches:

```
def cost(d1, m1, y1, d2, m2, y2):
    yd=0
    md=0
    dd = 0
    if (y1==y2):
        yd=0
    else: yd=abs(y1-y2)
    if (m1==m2):
        md=0
    else: md=abs(m1-m2)
    if (d1==d2):
        dd=0
    else: dd=abs(d1-d2)
    cost = int()
    if (md>11 or yd>0):
        cost = 20000
    elif (md>0 and md<12):
        cost = 1000*md
    elif (dd==0 and md==0 and yd==0):
        cost = 20
    elif (dd>0 and md==0 and yd==0):
        cost = dd*30
    print("yd=",yd)
    print("md=",md)
    print("dd=",dd)
    return cost

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #d1M1Y1 = input().split()
    d1M1Y1 = [6,1,2020]
    d1 = int(d1M1Y1[0])
    m1 = int(d1M1Y1[1])
    y1 = int(d1M1Y1[2])

    #d2M2Y2 = input().split()
    d2M2Y2 = [4,1,2021]
    d2 = int(d2M2Y2[0])
    m2 = int(d2M2Y2[1])
    y2 = int(d2M2Y2[2])
    
    result = server_cost(d1, m1, y1, d2, m2, y2)
    print(str(result) + '\n')
```

Comment: You better convert the strings to date and then compare.

Comment: Why don’t use use `datetime.strpdate()` to decode the strings to a `datetime.datetime`, then you can compare the values using `> `and `<`

Comment: @RA3 are you allowed to convert input to date time as stated above ? check [date time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226898/python-3-2-input-date-function). Best

Comment: You can then subtract dates and get the number of days and number of months without having to worry about complex logic.

Comment: I advise you to add 1 day to the end date to simplify your logic. When you subtract dates, if difference is 1 day then 20, if difference is greater than 1 day but less than a month then you directly multiply the difference in days by 30 and so on. Otherwise you will fall into edge cases.

Comment: What is this conditional: `if (md>11 or yd>0): cost = 20000 ...` supposed to mean? Months numbers range from 1 to 12, so they'll _never_ differ more than by 11. And years are different when you step from 31 December to 01 January – but they are just one day apart! Should a one day delay cost 20000...?

Comment: Please specify: are you interested in **differences in day, month and year numbers** (based on your description, 05 May and 25 May may be considered both _'within a month'_, namely within May, but 28 May and 3 June would not, despite being just a week apart), or in **delay in days** recalculated to 'months' equal, say, 30 days, and years, equal 365 days (so that 15 September and 2 October are _'within a month'_, because they are just 16 days apart, which is less than 30)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime
def cost(d1, m1, y1, d2, m2, y2):
    date1 = datetime.datetime(y1, m1, d1)
    date2 = datetime.datetime(y2, m2, d2)
    delta = date2 - date1
    if delta.days <= 1:
        return 20
    elif delta.days < 30:
        return 30 * delta.days
    elif delta.days < 365:
        return 1000 * (delta.days//12) # use a function that suits your def of months
    else:
        return 20000
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment, best to convert to datetime

E.g.

```
import datetime

d1M1Y1 = [6,1,2020]
d1 = int(d1M1Y1[0])
m1 = int(d1M1Y1[1])
y1 = int(d1M1Y1[2])

#d2M2Y2 = input().split()
d2M2Y2 = [4,1,2021]
d2 = int(d2M2Y2[0])
m2 = int(d2M2Y2[1])
y2 = int(d2M2Y2[2])


date1 = datetime.datetime(y1, m1, d1)

date2 = datetime.datetime(y2, m2, d2)

print(date1)
print(date2)
```

EDIT: Demo for working with datetime differences

```
dateTimeDifference = date2 - date1

# Datedifferene in days
daysDifference = dateTimeDifference.total_seconds() / 86400
print(daysDifference)

if daysDifference > 365:
    print ("More than a year")

else:
    print("Less than a year")
```

Comment: To provide a complete answer, please show how to manipulate datetime intervals.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import datetime

def str_to_date(str):
    fmt = '%d %m %Y'
    time_tuple = time.strptime(str, fmt)
    day, month, year = time_tuple[:3]
    a_date = datetime.date(day, month, year)
    return a_date

a = str_to_date('22 7 2020')
b = str_to_date('5 8 2019')

c = abs(a-b)
if c.days<=1:
    cost=20
elif c.days<30:
    cost=30*c.days
elif c.days<365:
    cost=1000*(c.days//30)
else:
    cost=20000

print(cost)
```