# How do I ask user for date input in python?

Tags: python

I want to make **def function** for schedules.
Here's what I imagine:
User input: yyyy-mm-dd
Output: the next day after the input, next 2 days, next 4 days

I tried to make the function but it doesn't work, please help. Thank you

Comment: What did you try, please provide the code

Comment: Can you share what you have done. Also have you checked Stack Overflow for examples? There are so many examples

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3.2 input date function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226898/python-3-2-input-date-function)

Answer (score -1):

This question is already answered here:

[Python 3.2 input date function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226898/python-3-2-input-date-function)

To add 2 days to the input date you would have to do something like:

```
date = datetime.date(year, month, day)
new_date = date  + timedelta(2)
```

Comment: Flag it as a duplicate